# What does it matter that this angle is the smallest between these two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have found several exercises of this form:

> Have two vectors $a$ and $b$. If $|a| = 10$ and $|b| = 5$, and the
>   smallest angle between the two is $\pi/4$, what must be the value of
>   $a\cdot b$?

I take it that

$$a\cdot b = |a| \cdot |b| \cdot \cos(\theta)$$

So I guess the answer is

$$10\cdot5\cdot\cos(\pi/4)$$
$$=49.99$$

But I wonder: all the exercises are very explicit when saying that $\theta$ is the **smallest** angle between the two vectors. I did not take this fact into account in any of my calculations, as I was unaware of its relevance.

My question is then: for this kind of problem, what does it matter that the given angle is the smallest between the two vectors?

Comment: You should have gotten $10 \cdot 5 \cdot \cos(\pi/4) \approx 35.36$ not $49.99$. Make sure your calculator is in radians not degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos \theta$ is correct, but I don't think that being the smallest angle matters. If $\theta$ is the smallest angle, then $2\pi - \theta$ is the greatest angle. And: $$\cos(2\pi-\theta) = \cos 2\pi \cos\theta + \sin 2\pi \sin \theta = \cos \theta.$$